delayWhen with inner EMPTY observable, does not emit any value
I wanted to test if delayWhen needs a value-emission to work or if a complete-signal from the passed observable is also enough.
To test this, I wrote this piece of code:
import { of, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { delayWhen, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';


const a$ = of('Hello');
const delay$ = EMPTY.pipe(delay(2000));
const new$ = a$.pipe(delayWhen(() => delay$));

new$.subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log('Value:', value),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete'),
  error: (err) => console.error('Error:', err),
});

I expected to get a console log that logs 'Hello' and then a 'Complete'-Message, but this did not happen.
Instead I see only a complete-Message.
Check out the result here.
Two questions:

Is delayWhen also working if the inner observable just completes?
Why is my way to 'test' this above not working as expected?


Okay, I understand my problem now.
It seems that the behaviour of delayWhen changed since Version 7:
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delayWhen
I now get why my code behaves like it does. However, I do not see any advantage in the change.

Before RxJS V7, the completion of the "duration" Observable would have
been triggering the emission of the source value to the output
Observable, but with RxJS V7, this is not the case anymore.


EMPTY only emits the complete notification as per docs, so the stream immediately complete hence you are getting only complete logged. So completed EMPTY does not wait for delay(2000ms) to happen.
Instead use of(true) followed by delay, of will emit and then complete, in this scenario, the delay works fine, since it's an emit, followed by a complete. So it will log Value: Hello; complete.
So a complete notification does not care what the downstream operations do, it just completes ASAP.
import { of, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { delayWhen, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Quell-Observable, das sofort einen Wert emittiert und dann abschließt
const a$ = of('Hello');

// Inneres Observable, das nach 2 Sekunden einfach nur abschließt
const delay$ = of(true).pipe(delay(2000));

// Neues Observable mit delayWhen
const new$ = a$.pipe(delayWhen(() => delay$));

// Subscribe to the new observable to see the behavior
new$.subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log('Value:', value),
  complete: () => console.log('Complete'),
  error: (err) => console.error('Error:', err),
});

Stackblitz Demo

Okay, thanks! But my other question, if delayWhen also works if the passed observable just completes, was not answered. Can you add this? :)

@David Yes I answered that, just complete - no, it stops the stream, if it emits and then completed, the stream is followed for the emit alone

It makes sense to me that "const delay$ = EMPTY.pipe(delay(2000))" ignores the delay beacause EMPTY just completes and all pipes later do not matter anymore. But that is just the parameter for delayWhen, so for me its still unclear why the 'Hello' from the outer observable is not emitted.

@DavidMason That is the problem with EMPTY since it's in the downstream and completes immediately, the upstream value of hello is not reaching the end of the stream and discarded when the empty completes

Ah! If you look in the docs my code would have worked as expected in rxjs6, but in version 7 they changed this behaviour: "Before RxJS V7, the completion of the "duration" Observable would have been triggering the emission of the source value to the output Observable, but with RxJS V7, this is not the case anymore." Look here: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delayWhen I think this change was bad. I don't think its intuitive and it broke my code.
